# How to keep collection view cell selected when presenting and dismissing modal view controller?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that is also acts as `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to size cells. One cell selection modally presents some custom controls and then returns when completed, but the selected cell is no longer selected when it reappears.

I see delegate method for `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` being called, but not `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. I also see the layout being asked for the preferred cell size, so I’m thinking they are being redrawn, but the cells already exist.

I can solve the problem by calling `relaodData()`, and the cell knows it is selected, and is redrawn accordingly, but that seems like a costly and wrong solution. Any suggestions about what I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

`UICollectionViewController` has property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` that is automatically set to true.

All I had to do was set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) being called, but not collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: Could you provide some context and use code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the following delegate method deselects the cell.

Override it without calling super:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: I override this function to modally present the view controller that ultimately causes the problem. So if I leave the implementation empty, the offending view controller is never presented. Is there a better method than this one to present a view controller when a certain cell is selected?

Comment: @Yarn, I wanted to mean do not call super, I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see delegate method for collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) being called, but not collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath). I also see the layout being asked for the preferred cell size, so I’m thinking they are being redrawn, but the cells already exist.